# $\mathcal S=\{A\in\mathcal F\mid \mathbf P(A)\in\{0,1\}\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

> Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbf P)$ be a probability space. Let
>   $\mathcal S=\{A\in\mathcal F\mid \mathbf P(A)\in\{0,1\}\}$. Show that
>   $\mathcal S$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Clearly, $\emptyset,\Omega\in\mathcal S$ and if $A\in\mathcal S$, then $ A^c\in\mathcal S$. Assume that $A_1,A_2,\ldots\in\mathcal S$. I need to show that $A=\cup_{n\geq 1}A_n\in\mathcal F$. Let $B_1=A_1$ and $$B_n=A_n\cap(\cap_{m=1}^{n-1}A_m^c)$$ for $n\geq 2$. Then $B_n$ are disjoint and $\cup_{n\geq 1}B_n=A$. So, $\mathbf P(A)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\mathbf P(B_n)$. But, it is still not clear why $\mathbf P(A)\in\{0,1\}$. I have also tried in vain to make an increasing sequence $C_n\uparrow A$ and use the continuity from below. If anyone could help me with the $n=2$ case, I guess I can take it from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need closed under complements and countable unions.

Suppose $A_k \in {\cal S}$, then $PA_k \in \{0,1\}$ for all $k$. If $PA_k = 1$ for any $k$ then $P (\cup_k A_k) \ge PA_k = 1$, otherwise $PA_k = 0$ for all $k$ and
$P(\cup_k A_k) \le \sum_k PA_k = 0$.